# Concatenate Strings in C/C++

Tags: c++, android, c, string

How do I concatenate Strings with C/C++?

I tried the following ways:

PS: errorInfo is a char * I should return it.

```
        errorInfo = strcat("Workflow: ", strcat(
            workflowToString(workflow).utf8(), strcat(" ERROR: ",
                    errorCode.utf8)));

        sprintf(errorInfo, "Workflow %s ERROR: %s",
            workflowToString(workflow).utf8(), errorCode.utf8());

        errorInfo = "Workflow: " + workflowToString(workflow).utf8() + " ERROR: " + errorCode.utf8;
```

Just the sprintf compiles but when running my application crash.

PS: I'm using NDK from Android

Comment: All the dots make it appear like you're using `C++` (there is no `C/C++`). I think that using `std::string` is your best bet: don't use `char *`!

Comment: What do you mean, "errorInfo is a char* I should return it"? `char*` is a pointer that may or may not be initialized, if so pointing to some memory that may or may not be a string, may or may not have enough space for the string you're createing, and has a lifetime that may or may not match what your caller expects. If you don't know anything about memory allocation in C or C++, then it's urgent that you read a book about one or both of them. There are at least 5 or 6 ways of writing a C++ function to join all this stuff together and return it, and you and your caller need to agree on one.

Comment: http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Memory-allocation.html gives a tutorial on C memory allocation.  If you've never dabbled in C before, don't worry.  Memory stuff can be tricky.  Just keep practicing.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) `strcat` does the following:

> Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a new null-character is appended at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

In your implementation, however, `"Workflow: "` is a constant string.  You cannot modify that string, which is what `strcat` would do.  In order to do that, create a string like:

```
char message[1000];
strcpy(message, "Workflow: ");
strcat(message, "other string");
....
```

However, be careful about the utf8 character encoding because one utf8 code point could be multiple `char`s long.

Comment: Okay, and how do I get the char[] as a char*?

Comment: @Armen: point taken.  Thank you.
@Marcos: in light of what Armen shared, cast the char[] as a char*.

Comment: Perfect, this works for me. And I dont casted it, just "errorInfo = message"

Answer (score 19):

There ***ISN'T*** such a language as C/C++. There is C, and there is C++.

- In C++ you concatenate `std::string`'s by using `operator+`
- In C, you use strcat

I know this doesn't quite answer your question, this is just an outcry :)

Comment: Thank's I talk about C/C++ cause any solution should work for me.

Comment: You cannot talk about C/C++ because there is no such thing as C/C++.

Comment: Just throwing oil on the fire here, but since the guy is asking for a syntax advice and that he could achieve the same results with little manipulation of his initial char array, I think you guys are being a little harsh.  Also, considering C++ is a superset of C, you think it would be wrong for someone to ask: "How do I calculate the area for a Rectangle/Square".  I'm pretty sure W*H does that, just like strcat can be use in a C++ context to concatenate strings.

Comment: I'm going to argue that you're wrong. MANY C++ programmers intersperse C functions within their code. A class object may call strcat internally, I see this all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenation is almost always the wrong idiom for string building, especially in C. It's error-prone, clutters your code, and has extremely bad asymptotic performance (i.e. `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)` for building a string of length `n`).

Instead you should use the `snprintf` function, as in:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "Workflow: %s ERROR: %s", workflow, error);
```

or if you're writing to a file/socket/etc. and don't need to keep the resulting string in memory, simply use `fprintf` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

By using `strcat()`, you are working in c, not c++.
c is not going to automatically manage memory for you. 
c can be confusing since sometimes it seems like it has a string data type when all it is doing is providing you a string interface to arrays of characters.
For one thing, the first argument to `strcat()` has to be writable and have enough room to add the second string.

```
char *out = strcat("This", "nThat");
```

is asking c to stomp on string literal memory.

In general, you should NEVER use `strcat()/sprintf`, as in the above "chosen" answer. You can overwrite memory that way. Use `strncat()/snprintf()` instead to avoid buffer overruns. If you don't know the size to pass to "n" in `strncat()`, you're likely doing something wrong.

One way to do this in c would be:

```
 #define ERROR_BUF_SIZE  2048  // or something big enough, you have to know in c




char errorInfo[ERROR_BUF_SIZE];

   snprintf(errorInfo, ERROR_BUF_SIZE, "Workflow %s ERROR: %s",
            workflowToString(workflow).utf8(), errorCode.utf8());
```

or similarly using `strncpy/strncat`

Answer (score 1):

With string literals you can simple use:

```
char str[] = "foo" " bar";
const char *s = " 1 " " 2 ";
s = " 3 " " 4 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can concatenate in C while using Android NDK:

Two ways I used are:

- strcat
- sprintf

here is example:

enter code here

strcat

```
char* buffer1=(char*)malloc(250000);
char* buffer2=(char*)malloc(250000);
char* buffer3=(char*)malloc(250000);

buffer1 = strcat(buffer1, buffer2);
```

sprintf

```
sprintf(buffer3,"this is buffer1: %s and this is buffer2:%s",buffer1,buffer2);`
```

sprintf returns length of your string

strcat is not recommended as its use more memory..
you can use sprintf or others like strcpy.

Hope it helps.