# How to repair "invalid operands of types 'const char' to binary 'operator+'?

Tags: c++, concatenation, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I concatenate multiple C++ strings on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662918/how-do-i-concatenate-multiple-c-strings-on-one-line)

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5354179/398460) a C++ std::string is concatenated by using operator+.
Why then does this code

```
using namespace std;
string sql = "create table m_table(" + 
    "path TEXT," +
    "quality REAL," +
    "found INTEGER);";
```

cause this error?

> invalid operands of types 'const char [22]' and 'const char [17]' to
>   binary 'operator+'

Comment: Those aren't C++ string objects you're trying to concatenate, but C strings.  String literals are C strings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What chris said, but in this particular case you can do

```
string sql = "create table m_table("
    "path TEXT,"
    "quality REAL,"
    "found INTEGER);";
```

Which will concatenate strings *at compile time*.

Comment: Yes. This works for a set of const strings which I will use in this case but I probably also need what Chris said for the `insert into m_table` case which has variables and which I neglected to mention.

Comment: @jacknad, As long as those variables are `std::string`s, you can do something like `string s = "abc" "def" + otherString + "ghi";`

Comment: Haven't touched C++ in a while. Between C, Java, C#, Vala, Python, etc., my head is spinning. But each has its own charm.

Comment: Yes, that + consider parametrized queries.

Comment: `c++` is the most charming! ;-)

Answer (score 12):

You need to explicitly convert it to a string to match the argument list:

```
string sql = std::string("create table m_table(") + 
"path TEXT," +
"quality REAL," +
"found INTEGER);";
```

Now the first one is a string matched up with a `const char[N]`, which matches one of the `operator+` overloads and returns a new `std::string`, which is used to repeat the process for the rest.

Comment: +1 but see my comment for the case like this.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but could you do `std::string sql = /* String literals */`?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, Yes, very good point. It's often the case that there's a `char *` variable as one of the first two arguments, in which case you would need to explicitly convert one, but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: @chris, yes that's why I say *for the case like this*. In particular, for `sql` I'd prefer parametrized query ;)

Comment: @jacknad, I'd really consider accepting Michael's answer. It applies to your situation much better than this does since they're all literals.

Answer (score 1):

a better way is to use std::ostringstream

```
#include <sstream>

const std::string myFunc(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
  std::ostringstream os;
  os<<s1<<" "<<s2;
  return os.str();
}
```

The advantage is that you can use the std::ostream << operator overloads to stringify non string values too

Comment: How's throwing in heckuvalotta resources "better"?

Comment: It is useful to be able to combine other types into a string, but I don't think there's any need to change simple string concatenation to get that. I think sticking with operator+ and just using `std::to_string()` or similar functions is a better way: `"hello" + std::to_string(50)`. lexical_cast even lets you do this with any type that has an ostream `operator<<`: `"Hello, " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(myFoo)`

Comment: Michael, it's better if you need to concatenate just more than strings and/or (by using std::wostringstream) need to handle wide char strings etc. the stringstream classes in STL were provided specifically for these type of usecases, extending the iostreams paradigm. the std::ostream semantics for formatting, precision, width etc. can also come into play here.

Comment: @mohaps: well, I would avoid using the pesky implementation-defined wide characters; best way not to have portable programs.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Amen to that! :) But in a large enough codebase with pesky little legacy thirdparty libraries... it's better to plan ahead and allow for the dreaded wchar_t stuff.

Comment: @mohaps: well, programming only for the linux world, they are pretty rare since it's utf-8 everywhere :D

Comment: There's still `std::towstring` by the way.